# Do memory mapped files provide advantage for large buffers?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, mmap, large-data

My program works with large data sets that need to be stored in contiguous memory (several Gigabytes). Allocating memory using `std::allocator` (i.e. `malloc` or `new`) causes system stalls as large portions of virtual memory are reserved and physical memory gets filled up.

Since the program will mostly only work on small portions at a time, my question is if using memory mapped files would provide an advantage (i.e. `mmap` or the Windows equivalent.) That is creating a large sparse temporary file and mapping it to virtual memory. Or is there another technique that would change the system's pagination strategy such that less pages are loaded into physical memory at a time.

I'm trying to avoid building a streaming mechanism that loads portions of a file at a time and instead rely on the system's vm pagination.

Comment: how frequently will you jump between portions?

Comment: It depends on the algorithms (many different). Basically they would fall into these categories:
- Sequential reading from begin to end
- Parallel sequential reading in different large segments 
- Random access within a large segment (e.g. during recursive depth first descent)
- Other random access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `mmap` has the *potential* to speed things up.

Things to consider:

- Remember the VMM will page things in and out in page size blocked (4k on Linux)
- If your memory access is well localised over time, this will work well. But if you do random access over your entire file, you will end up with a lot of seeking and thrashing (still). So, consider whether your 'small portions' correspond with localised bits of the file.
- For large allocations, `malloc` and `free` will use `mmap` with `MAP_ANON` anyway. So the difference in memory mapping a file is simply that you are getting the VMM to do the I/O for you.
- Consider using `madvise` with `mmap` to assist the VMM in paging well.
- When you use `open` and `read` (plus, as erenon suggests, `posix_fadvise`), your file is still held in buffers anyway (i.e. it's not immediately written out) unless you also use `O_DIRECT`. So in both situations, you are relying on the kernel for I/O scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is already in a file, it would speed up things, especially in the non-sequential case. (In the sequential case, `read` wins)

If using `open` and `read`, consider using [posix_fadvise](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) as well.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your `mmap()` implementation. Mapping a file into memory has several advantages that can be exploited by the kernel:

- The kernel knows that the contents of the `mmap()` pages is already present on disk. If it decides to evict these pages, it can omit the write back.
- You reduce copying operations: `read()` operations typically first read the data into kernel memory, then copy it over to user space.
- The reduced copies also mean that less memory is used to store data from the file, which means more memory is available for other uses, which can reduce paging as well.

  This is also, why it is generally a bad idea to use large caches within an I/O library: Modern kernels already cache *everything* they ever read from disk, caching a copy in user space means that the amount of data that can be cached is actually reduced.

Of course, you also avoid a lot of headaches that result from buffering data of unknown size in your application. But that is just a convenience for you as a programmer.

However, even though the kernel *can* exploit these properties, it does not necessarily *do* so. My experience is that LINUX `mmap()` is generally fine; on AIX, however, I have witnessed really bad `mmap()` performance. So, if your goal is performance, it's the old measure-compare-decide stand by.